# ant patternset partial set

Tags: regex, ant

Reading https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html, it says

*"*These patterns look very much like the patterns used in DOS and UNIX:
'*' matches zero or more characters, '?' matches one character."*

I'd like to clean up the following (simple eg:) as I think the second form is more concise and readable (if you know regex patterns, of course):

```
<copy todir="${target.dir}" flatten="true" >
   <fileset dir="${source.dir}" >
      <include name="**/*.war" />
      <include name="**/*.ear" />
      <include name="**/*.gar" />
      <exclude name="some-dir/**" />
   </fileset>
</copy>
```

To be something like:

```
   <include name="**/*.[weg]ar" />
```

but that is not supported, even though it is UNIX-like.

```
          <include name="**/*.?ar" />
```

Is not adequate as I don't want to include "*.jar"

What is the most effective way of accomplishing this?

ps:still on ant-1.7.1

Comment: I don't think that you can do this. This is not a regular expression syntax but _globbing_. You only have the `*` and `?` features but these are glob characters not regex symbols.

Comment: Yes, I recognize this is the only option available within the copy / include construct, but is there an alternative solution with a resource collection or something ... the equivalent of a `"find * -name "*.[weg]ar"`, which would resolve and can then be used in the copy ?

Answer (score 1):

you should upgrade the ant Version ( >= 1.8.x ) , then use :

```
<copy todir="${target.dir}" flatten="true" >
 <fileset dir="${source.dir}" >
   <filename regex=".*\.[weg]ar"/>  
 </fileset>
</copy>
```